# iOS Sidebar UIPanGestureRecognizer - Sliding Centre View Between coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, sidebar, limits

I've been trying to work this one out based on a tutorial I've been following from Ray Wenderlich's tutorials.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

I only want my nav bar to have a left sided slide menu (I don't need the right sided menu that is in the example)

When I am using the gestures to swipe I can't find a good way to stop the view from going any further to the right than the position I want it set to when the menu is open (100pts from the right). When I swipe it back into position I don't want the view to swipe any further than 0 (I don't want it's x value to be negative).

With the current Facebook iOS App (55.0 - 12 May 2016) there is a side menu for chat. That's the exact functionality I am after (but on the left side instead of right).

Comment: With the current Facebook iOS App (55.0 - 12 May 2016) there is a side menu for chat. That's the exact functionality I am after (but on the left side instead of right).

Comment: Rather than adding clarifying information for your original post in a comment, just edit your question to include this clarifying information; that way, it's easier for people to follow the thread.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've done that now :-)